# Bitmap to big to use getPixels?

Tags: android, memory, colors, bitmap

If I make a picture with mine samsung galaxy s2, the picture is 3264 x 2448 px.
I want to use a color range check on that, but it doesn't work.

However, if I make the picture smaller for example, 2500 x 2500 (so less pixels), then it does work. But I want the use the picture size of the galaxy s2 (3264 x 2448).
I think it is a memory issue?
I don't exactly know anymore what the limit is.
But is their another way to "bypass" this issue?

This is a piece of code, how I do it now:

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.four_colors);

int width = bmp.getWidth();
int height = bmp.getHeight();
int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                     int index = y * width + x;
                     int R = (pixels[index] >> 16) & 0xff;     //bitwise shifting
                     int G = (pixels[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
                     int B = pixels[index] & 0xff;
                     total++;
                     if ((G > R)&&(G > B)){
                         counter++;
                    }
            }
}
```

It crashes because the picture is to big, smaller pics work.
So is their something to "bypass" this issue? instead of using smaller images :)

I tried some other things, without succes, I try to explain what I tried.

1. I tried to "cut" the image in two, and then scan it separate (didn't work).
2. and I tried to only scan the half of it (1632 x 1224) then rotate the image (180 degrees) and scan it again, but also this didn't work out.
3. Hit me :)

Comment: Hey, I am going to try the answers tomorrow.
I will let you hear what came out of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When playing around with huge images you really should be using the [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) to process it in chunks.

**Edit** - now with a simple example:

```
    try {
        // Processes file in res/raw/huge.jpg or png
        BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.huge), false);
        try  {
            final int width = decoder.getWidth();
            final int height = decoder.getHeight();
            // Divide the bitmap into 1024x768 sized chunks and process it.
            int wSteps = (int) Math.ceil(width / 1024.0);
            int hSteps = (int) Math.ceil(height / 768.0);
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            long total = 0L, counter = 0L;
            for (int h = 0; h < hSteps; h++) {
                for (int w = 0; w < wSteps; w++) {
                    int w2 = Math.min(width, (w + 1) * 1024);
                    int h2 = Math.min(height, (h + 1) * 768);
                    rect.set(w * 1024, h * 768, w2, h2);
                    Bitmap bitmap = decoder.decodeRegion(rect, null);
                    try {
                        int bWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
                        int bHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
                        int[] pixels = new int[bWidth * bHeight];
                        bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bWidth, 0, 0, bWidth, bHeight);
                        for (int y = 0; y < bHeight; y++){
                            for (int x = 0; x < bWidth; x++){
                                int index = y * bWidth + x;
                                int R = (pixels[index] >> 16) & 0xff;     //bitwise shifting
                                int G = (pixels[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
                                int B = pixels[index] & 0xff;
                                total++;
                                if ((G > R)&&(G > B)){
                                    counter++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        bitmap.recycle();
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            decoder.recycle();
        }
```

Comment: Hey, somehow I don't get the BitmapRegionDecoder to work.
How to use it?

Comment: The documentation is pretty straightforward though? You typically have to place huge resources in res/raw or assets though.

Comment: Just started with Java last week. So it was all new for me.
I modified the code you posted a little bit, so it worked in my own code.

I am first going to learn / understand the code you posted completely before I go on.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: How can I rejoin all divided bitmaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the amount of pixel data of the image that you are loading at once by using some of the parameters of the getPixels method.  I did something very similar, and I would read them one row at a time, for example.

```
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, y, width, 1);
```